# Android: AsyncTask ProgressDialog will not open in ActivityGroup

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, activitygroup

I am trying to have a a progress dialog open when polling my server.  The class is an ActivityGroup because it is nested within a tab bar. To keep the view within the frame, the ActivityGroup is needed.  Here is the declaration of my ActivityGroup class:

```
   public class CheckInActivity extends ActivityGroup{
        ...
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.checkin);
            new LocationControl().execute(this);
```

Now my AsyncTask class is within the same CheckInActivityClass as such:

```
private class LocationControl extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void>
    {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(CheckInActivity.this);

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Determining your location...");
            this.dialog.show();
        }
```

When I run the given app it throughs an error relating to WindowManager$BadTokenException.  Stating the it cannot start the window with an unknown token.  I tried making a sample app that is just a regular Activity(not ActivityGroup) and it worked just fine.

Does anyone know how to modify this to make it work, or a work around that will allow the progress bar to be nested within the tab bar?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the ActivityGroup is within a TabActivity you have nested activities with more then two levels. Android doesn't support this at the moment but there is a workaround. You have to pass the parent activity to the dialog.

Create a helper method for this purpose in the activity class:

```
private Context getDialogContext() {
    Context context;
    if (getParent() != null) context = getParent();
    else context = this;
    return context;
}
```

Then change the line

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(CheckInActivity.this);
```

to

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getDialogContext());
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple here you can also use following

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
```

it work perfectly for me .

Answer (score 1):

If getParent() doesn't work for you, try using just `TabsActivity.context` (or substitute the name of your parent tab activity class). I am using nested activities and as a result using getParent() is still not returning the right context for the dialog, since it needs the context of the activity extending TabsActivity, not the immediate parent.

Simple fix:

1. You'll need to create a context variable in the TabsActivity class. Something like `public static TabsActivity context;` and `context=this` in the onCreate method.
2. Replace this line where you create the dialog:

   `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`

With:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TabsActivity.context);
```

and it works like a charm.