# Click on spinner gives WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity, android-context

I am using Tabwidget, Tab are implemented in same way which shows in [tutorial](http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

"MainActivity -> Activity1 -> Activity2(given Image)"

[image: view for the current activity]

Now clicking on the spinner gives

```
 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44eb8748 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

I have tried [Android Spinner Error : android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609519/android-spinner-error-android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to) already but that doesn't help me

I know There is **something wrong with context** but I can't figure out what

Hear is my Intent which starts `DetailActivity`

```
intent = new Intent(getParent(), DetailActivity.class);
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
parentActivity.startChildActivity("SelectActivity", intent);
```

My code for the `DetailActivity` given bellow

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.package_detail);
        setUpViews();

        id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("WEBSITE_ID");

        adapter = new KeywordAdapter(getApplicationContext(), id,
                getLNApplication().getKeyworddetail());
        listTags.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinneAdapter = new SpinnerListAdapter();
        spinnerList.setAdapter(spinneAdapter);
        spinnerList.setSelection(id, true);
        spinnerList
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {

                        // txtHeader.setText(getLNApplication().getWebsiteList()
                        // .get(position).getName());
                        adapter.forceReload();
                        adapter = new KeywordAdapter(DetailActivity.this,
                                position, getLNApplication().getKeyworddetail());
                        listTags.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

    }
```

code for `SpinnerAdapter`

```
public class SpinnerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<ClientDetail> siteList;

        public SpinnerListAdapter() {
            siteList = getLNApplication().getWebsiteList();
        }
        
        public void forceReload() {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return siteList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return siteList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            
//          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
//              .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    
//          LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    
//          LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(DetailActivity.this.getParent());
    
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(DetailActivity.this.getParent());
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_display, null);
                TextView websiteName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerItem);
            if (siteList.get(position).getName() != null) {
                websiteName.setText(siteList.get(position).getName());
                websiteName.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            }
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            
//          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
//                  .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            
//          LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            
//          LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(DetailActivity.this.getParent());
            
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(DetailActivity.this.getParent());
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_display, null);
                TextView websiteName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerDropDownItem);
            if (siteList.get(position).getName() != null) {
                websiteName.setText(siteList.get(position).getName());
                websiteName.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Am i doing anything wrong?

please help me with... Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass

```
YourActivty.this.getParent()
```

as `Context` to the `Spinner`.

For more information see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7119142/593709) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143493/593709)

Comment: I have tried that before but that didn't work, so I put SpinnerListAdapter class in the same class and passing nothing as a parameter wherever I need to use context I am  using Class.this.getParent() look for the LayoutInflater in SpinnerListAdapter class

Comment: @Adil paste above line on my code but when i click on spinner gives me same error.

Answer (score 1):

In Tab activity if you are giving any alert dialog then in that case you have set context of the tab activity & not the current activity object.

instead of

```
adapter = new KeywordAdapter(getApplicationContext(),id,getLNApplication().getKeyworddetail());
listTags.setAdapter(adapter);
```

use the following

```
adapter = new KeywordAdapter(Tabs.ctx,id,getLNApplication().getKeyworddetail());
listTags.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where Tabs.ctx is the context of tab activity & that is static variable.

Comment: it is the adapter for the listview spinner adapter is spinneAdapter

Comment: if u are creating spinner dynamically @ that time Spinner spinner = new Spinner(Tabs.ctx);

Comment: Tabs.ctx means ActivtyClass.this or something else

Comment: it is the contex of that activity for that in tab activity u have to create one static variable which will hold refrence of that activity like public static Tabs ctx; ctx = this ; in tab activity.

Comment: I have created context like this public static Context ctx = MainActivity.this; but didn't work

Comment: public static Tabs ctx; ctx = Tabs.this ; in this case Tabs is my tab activity & i am creating context of that tab activity. i thing u r doing wrong way.

Comment: I can not find Tabs in my library... plz guide me!!

Comment: just mail me u r code i wll check that on sumant4943@gmail.com

Comment: i have mailed you code tell me if you found problem in run the project Thanks so much

Comment: oops I just remembered you are not gonna run the application because it uses some local services which are not live yet

Answer (score 0):

In `TabWidget` also using this code you can solved this error

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.package_detail, null);
this.setContentView(view);
```